# Sqlite ordering/sorting for turkish alphabet

Tags: python, django, sqlite

How can I sort letters for Turkish alphabet? Can I do it with a function?

```py
def a(request):
    keyword = request.GET.get("keyword")
    if keyword:
        makaleler = Makale.objects.filter(title__contains = keyword)
        return render(request,"a.html",{"makaleler":makaleler})
    makaleler = Makale.objects.filter(title__startswith="A").order_by("title")
    context = {
        "makaleler":makaleler
    }
    return render(request, "a.html",context)
```

Comment: Look into using the Unicode-aware  collations from the [ICU](https://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/dir?name=ext/icu) extension. (Turkish is even one of the examples)

Comment: thnx @Shawn, it probably will solve my problem, however, I don't understand how to use it? Do I need to download something? Can u describe for me?

Comment: There is an example of how to compile it in the readme. You'll have to look in the python docs for how to load an extension module through it.